# Gradle project sync failed after update - Unable to find method 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;'

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I recently opened up an old project, updated Android Studio to 3.1.3, and am now unable to run the project. This is the message I receive:

```
Unable to find method 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;'.

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

This message is followed up by this one on the second attempt:

```
Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder
```

[Gradle Project sync failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhAwl.png)

The gradle project sync keeps failing, I've tried all of these solutions below, including invalidating/restarting cache, deleting .gradle file, etc.

[Unsuccessful solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsGtW.png)

I'm not an Android wiz, so if anyone can lead me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure it out eventually? I'm struggling with the same problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this has to do with conflicts in Guava depending on the 
Gradle version you use and the Guava version your dependencies use.

The function toImmutableList was added in [Guava 21](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) ([Guava 20](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)).

I suggest you try downgrading the project's gradle version to 3.3 or so and try again.